# Product Collection not find in module observer file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a module. it is working properly but when we get product collection in Observer.php file then this is not return any objects and collection. it is empty and also not create any expection or log file. please help me.

I have this code in observer.php file

```
class GWB_ClearOrphan_Model_Observer
{
    public function disableProducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        try{
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'collection.log');
        }
    }
}
```

I am also trying both product collection model method but collection not found.

1. `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');`
2. `$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load();`

Comment: can you please put model class here...

Comment: this is the code of observer.php --- <?php
class GWB_ClearOrphan_Model_Observer
{

   public function disableProducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
    try{ 
     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
     Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'collection.log');
    }
 
   }
  
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

will not load anything. You have to call `load()` method, like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load();
```

It would be better to know what you want to achieve, which event do you observe and why you want to load all products in your observer? You do not use any filters on collection, so in fact statement above will load all products, which can kill your request.

Comment: I have also call load method but this is also return empty set.

Comment: Please tell us what do you want to do in the observer and which event do you observe.

Comment: I am define and register custom event -- catalog_product_import_profile_after under this file -- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php . i want to load store products collection after run profile part in magento admin.